# Should I go for Debian Stable or Testing?

Tags: debian, security, distribution-choice, distributions, privacy

I've been using Debian Stable for 1 year. I like Debian for their Privacy Policy, no telemetry and security.
Now I need to reinstall my distro and I want to go for security distro. I don't know whether I should go for Debian Stable or Testing.

The reason I want to switch to Testing is newer kernels (they are more secure) because I sometimes fail when I try to compile a newer kernel or it takes too much time to compile and I think Testing is getting faster and includes newer security updates and packages such as apparmor and others.

Comment: If you have to ask, go for Stable.

Answer (score 3):

If your two main criteria are security support and updated kernels, I recommend installing Debian 9 (stable) and using the backported kernels — kernels which enter testing are regularly backported to stable. If you run Debian testing you need to keep an eye on security updates yourself; barring exceptional circumstances they are only pushed to unstable, and migrate to testing following the testing rules (see [the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting) for details), which means that in some cases they can take a while to become available. Paradoxically, as the Debian 10 release gets closer and the freeze comes into effect, this will become more of a problem (but the freeze is one of the circumstances in which security fixes are more likely to be pushed to testing explicitly).

To install such a kernel, add backports to the available repositories:

```
echo deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list
```

then update your package indexes:

```
sudo apt update
```

and install the latest backported kernel (here, for `amd64`)

```
sudo apt install -t stretch-backports linux-image-amd64
```